# Efficient way to divide many different terms and sum them up in java

Tags: java, algorithm, decimal, division, apfloat

I would like to know how to efficiently divide n terms and sum them up.
I have 2 Arrays each containing large Decimal which is stored by an external Library called Apfloat:

`Apfloat[] nume=new Apfloat[n];
 Apfloat[] deno==new Apfloat[n];`

Using a formula, I fill up `nume[]` with the numerators of some fractions and I fill up `deno[]` with the denominators of the same fractions. Now I want to find the sum of these fractions. So, at first I just divide each numerator by it's corresponding denominator and add each to a variable `sum` such that 
`sum=(nume[0]/deno[0])+(nume[1]/deno[1])+(nume[2]/deno[2])... +(nume[n]/deno[n]);`

However, that means that I have to divide `n` times and since dividing huge decimals is a very time consuming process, it cause the program to take a long time to finish.

I then tried finding the LCM of the denominators and multiplying the numerator and denominator by `k` such that the number * k = LCM. This gave me a single numerator and a single denominator at the end so I only needed to divide 1 time. However, in the process I had to multiply approximately `2n` times so, it was slower then the original method which, brings me to my question, **Is there a more efficient/faster method to achieve this?**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you precompute or cache it?

Comment: Why not use an `Aprational` array, or two `Apint` ones? There's even an `ApintMath.lcm(Apint a, Apint b)`.

Comment: @greybeard Yes, but with the LCM I would still have to multiply many times and ApintMath doesn't support lcm of more then 2 decimals at a time.

Comment: suggestion: sum rationals by denominator. I'm disappointed with what little I found documented about `apfloat` (Java as well as C++) - consider using a better documented/more widely known package, none crossing my mind for Java. (`decimals`? A constructive way to think about numbers _if_ conversion from/to human readable representations take more time than computations.)